# Open an encrypted HDD/USB on Leopard?

Tags: hard-drive, filevault, encryption, file-transfer

Is it possible to access an external HDD or USB drive encrypted on Lion, through a Mac running Leopard?

In other words, is FileVault 2 encryption on volumes/partitions backwards compatible? (It really should be.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - OS X older than Lion cannot read or comprehend/mount/use a [Core Storage volume](http://movies.apple.com/media/us/osx/2012/docs/OSX_MountainLion_Core_Technologies_Overview.pdf) such as used with [FileVault 2](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4790).

Someone could reverse engineer the protocol and write drivers for older OS or different OS, but I haven't even seen a start towards that effort in any open source project.

Comment: Thanks, that's unfortunate. Would have been nice if Apple had released an update.